# How do I calculate a grey value at reference point?

Tags: python, jython, rgb, pixel, jes

I need to Calculate the grey value at reference point – The grey value of the pixel is the average of its red, green and blue values. For instance, in the example the RGB values of the reference point at this stage would be 151, 161 and 137. Therefore, the grey value should be 149.66...

I need some tips on how i can do this in python? Im using jython! JES

Answer (score 0):

Then you'll calculate the average of these 3 values. Average is sum of the values divided by their number. In this case

```
grey = (r + g + b) / 3.0
```

And the grey value at that point is 151.67, not 149.67.